# Use one only first label

Tags: pgfplots, labels, appendices

I include (via `ìnput`) two times the same `pgfplot` from a different file. One time in the text and one time in a more detailed view in the appendix. Since the label is defined in the extra file, the latest one gets used (the one in the appendix).

I want that the second input does not redefine the label. How can I achieve that behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up things so that the label itself does the right thing:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-extra}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}

\singlelabel{extra}{\caption{An image}}
\end{figure}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\singlelabel}[2]{%
  \ifcsname singlelabel#1\endcsname
    % the file has already been read
    \@namedef{the\@captype}{\ref{#1}}%
    #2%
  \else
    #2\label{#1}
    \global\@namedef{singlelabel#1}{}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Title}

\input{\jobname-extra}

\appendix

\section{Title again}

\input{\jobname-extra}

\end{document}
```

I used `filecontents` just to make the example self-contained.

[image]

The numbering will be the same as for the original figure. If you want independent numbering, just comment out the

```
\@namedef{the\@captype}{\ref{#1}}%
```

line

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\@newl@bel#1#2#3{{%
  \@ifundefined{#1@#2}%
    {\global\@namedef{#1@#2}{#3}}%
    {\gdef \@multiplelabels {%
       \@latex@warning@no@line{There were multiply-defined labels}}%
     \@latex@warning@no@line{Label `#2' multiply defined}}%
  }}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{foo bar}\label{foo}
\subsection{foo baz}\label{foo}

\ref{foo}
\end{document}
```

**Explanation** Latex's `\label` cal the internal command `\@newl@bel`

```
\def\@newl@bel#1#2#3{{%
  \@ifundefined{#1@#2}%
    \relax
    {\gdef \@multiplelabels {%
       \@latex@warning@no@line{There were multiply-defined labels}}%
     \@latex@warning@no@line{Label `#2' multiply defined}}%
  \global\@namedef{#1@#2}{#3}}}
```

this is something like `ifundefined{label}{do nothing}{produce warning}` and then globaly define the label (so to last usage).

One can redefine this command to be `ifundefined{label}{globaly define the label}{produce warning}`

Comment: Thanks! Would you be so kind to provide a short explanation, so that I can understand the fix?

Comment: Explanation add, hope it helps.